# HTTPBuilder library

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, buildconfig

I want to use the HTTPBuilder class to send json Data to my server, I have imported the following namespaces, But my intelliJ IDEA is not recognizing the the "groovyx" saying can not resolve symbol.

```
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.Method
```

I have added the following to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
compile "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7"
```

Comment: Your question has already been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552697/how-to-import-groovyx-net-http).

Comment: Have you added this under `dependencies { .. }` or `plugins { .. }` section in BuildConfig?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with either your dependency or the packages you've imported.
Have you compiled your app since you added this dependency? If not, run `grails compile` and `grails refresh-dependencies` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: might also try 'grails refresh-dependencies'

Comment: I have compiled, and refreshed dependencies, but it does not effect, still getting same error. "Can not resolve symbol groovyx"