# Grails & Nexmo plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, vonage

I'm getting errors in Grails integrating Nexmo plugin. The file where the errors occured is 'NexmoService.groovy' as follows:

```
package grails.plugin.nexmo

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder as LCH

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST

class NexmoService {

    def grailsApplication
    def messageSource

    def sendSms(String to, String text, String from=config?.sms?.default_from) throws NexmoException {
        if (!to || !text || !from) {
            throw new NexmoException(getMessage("nexmo.sms.error.missing.param"))
        }

        def http = new HTTPBuilder(config?.endpoint)  
        def requestBody = [to: to, text: text, from: from, api_key: config?.api?.key, api_secret: config?.api?.secret]

        http.request(POST) {
            uri.path = "/sms/${config?.format}"
            send(URLENC, requestBody)

            response.success = { resp, data ->
                def message = data?.messages[0]
                def statusCode = message?.status
                if (statusCode != "0") {
                    def error = getMessage("nexmo.sms.status.${statusCode}", [message?."error-text"], getMessage("nexmo.sms.error.default"))
                    throw new NexmoException(error)
                }
                log.info(getMessage("nexmo.sms.success"))
                return [status: message?.status, id: message?."message-id"]
            }
            response.failure = { resp, data ->
                def error = getMessage("nexmo.sms.error.response", [resp?.status], getMessage("nexmo.sms.error.default"))
                throw new NexmoException(error)
            }
        }
    }

    def call(String to, String text, String from="") throws NexmoException {
        if (!to || !text) {
            throw new NexmoException(getMessage("nexmo.call.error.missing.param"))
        }

        def http = new HTTPBuilder(config?.endpoint)
        def requestBody = [to: to, text: text, from: from, api_key: config?.api?.key, api_secret: config?.api?.secret]

        http.request(POST) {
            uri.path = "/tts/${config?.format}"
            send(URLENC, requestBody)

            response.success = { resp, data ->
                def statusCode = data?.status
                if (statusCode != "0") {
                    def error = getMessage("nexmo.call.status.${statusCode}", [data?."error-text"], getMessage("nexmo.call.error.default"))
                    throw new NexmoException(error)
                }
                log.info(getMessage("nexmo.call.success"))
                return [status: data?.status, id: data?."call-id"]
            }
            response.failure = { resp, data ->
                def error = getMessage("nexmo.call.error.response", [resp?.status], getMessage("nexmo.call.error.default"))
                throw new NexmoException(error)
            }
        }
    }

    private ConfigObject getConfig() {
        return grailsApplication.config?.nexmo
    }

    private String getMessage(String code, List args=[], String defaultMessage="") {
        if (messageSource.resolveCode(code, LCH.locale)) {
            return messageSource.getMessage(code, args.toArray(), LCH.locale)
        }
        return defaultMessage
    }
}
```

**The errors are below:**

> | Error Compilation error: startup failed:
>   C:\nexmo-master\grails-app\services\grails\plugin\nexmo\NexmoService.groovy:
>   3: unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder  @ line 3,
>   column 1.    import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder    ^
>
> C:\nexmo-master\grails-app\services\grails\plugin\nexmo\NexmoService.groovy:
>   6: unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.ContentType  @ line 6,
>   column 1.    import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC    ^
>
> C:\nexmo-master\grails-app\services\grails\plugin\nexmo\NexmoService.groovy:
>   7: unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.Method  @ line 7, column
>   1.    import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST    ^
>
> 3 errors

Comment: It seems you are not getting the HTTPBuilder, which is needed and included by the Nexmo plugin. Maybe the Nexmo plugin is out of date with your current Grails version? You can try to include it yourself by including the REST plugin into your build config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have http-builder library in classpath. Look at this post for instructions to import this library. [How to import groovyx.net.http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552697/how-to-import-groovyx-net-http) or http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td3995735